# What are the required fields for ScapholdSchema?

Tags: graphql, scaphold

Can you explain what this schema means?

```
type ScapholdSchema {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
  types: [ScapholdType]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! That is GraphQL syntax for defining a type in the GraphQL schema. In this case, the type name is called `ScapholdSchema` and it has fields that are `id`, `name`, `description`, and `types`, respectively. Continuing down the hierarchy, each field has a type as well, some scalar and others as custom objects. In your snippet, the word to the right of the field name defines its type (`ID!`, `String!`, etc...).

To answer your question more directly, the exclamation mark means it's a non-null field (i.e. required). One final thing to note is the `ScapholdType` field type. This is GraphQL object that is defined elsewhere in the GraphQL type system (much like `ScapholdSchema` is here). And the brackets around it denote that the `types` field is a list of `ScapholdType` objects.

Hope that helps!